# Install Ubuntu on HCL Beanstalk Desktop?

Tags: 12.04, installation, downloads

I currently have a HCL Beanstalk desktop PC which is quite old now. I have another shared and quite new HCL Laptop with intel CORE i3 processor and it came with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it as it is a government laptop. Having used Ubuntu on that laptop now, I wish to install Ubuntu on my desktop as well. Can someone please provide me the link for the desktop version as I am quite a N00B in these matters and might end up with a bricked desktop. And after download, how do I install it from boot DVD?

Answer (score 0):

Click 'Read the full installation instructions' on [this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) for more help.

If main Ubuntu (Unity (3D)) isn't fast enough for that PC, you can try the 'Unity 2D' option if you get Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS, or you can use the following command to install the GNOME desktop and you can then select 'GNOME Fallback' when logging in for a lightweight-yet-Ubuntu desktop (to open a Terminal, press `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F1` then use `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F7` to switch back to the graphical desktop):

`sudo apt-get install gnome`